# Consultar CEP pela localização do usuário

Tags: javascript, geolocalização

Existe alguma forma de consultar o CEP a partir da localização do usuário, fornecida pelo navegador. Tipo dada a latitude e a longitude retornar o CEP das coordenadas passadas.

Seria algo como:

```
function getCEP(lantitude, longitute) {
  // retorna o cep associado as coordenadas passadas
}
```

Comment: Depende muito, eu já utilizei o serviço do Google Maps para isso, porém muitos endereços não trazem o CEP completo, ou nem trazem. Para solucionar montei minha base com o PostGIS carregando informações do OpenStreetMap e a base dos correios, da um certo trabalho porém o resultado é muito melhor. Sobre o serviço do Google você pode ver vários exemplos na própria documentação:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=pt-br
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Vlw @HeberMinetto conseguir resolver aqui, com sua dica. Usando o Google Maps, não é tão preciso assim como vc disse, mas funcionou certinho.

Comment: Se reabrir a pergunta posta minha solução...